# Cannot configure Intellij Groovy unit test JVM memory

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

In short, I tried to use Intellij `edit configurations` `VM` to add `-Xmx6g`, I tried adding to the environment using `GROOVY_OPTS`, I tried adding to `gradle.properties` as `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6g`

None worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all the above set the JVM for the gradle daemon, but tests run on a different JVM.
To set XMX for your tests, edit the `build.gradle` file by adding

```
test {
    minHeapSize = "2000m"
    maxHeapSize = "6000m"
}
```